# Create a custom SUM function with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table called ("Vendas2020") that has the daily sales and each row has either "C" or "V" if they're either a purchase or a sale (C/V column is the fifth one and is called "Compra / Venda"). I have inserted a function to only calculate the visible values in the table since the destination worksheet (which is a report called "Relatório") has slicers for the products, salesperson and year. The code for the sumfunction is as follows:

```
Function SUMVisible(Rg As Range)
  Dim xCell As Range
  Dim xCount As Integer
  Dim xTtl As Double

  Application.Volatile
  Set Rg = Intersect(Rg.Parent.UsedRange, Rg)

  For Each xCell In Rg
    If xCell.ColumnWidth > 0 _
       And xCell.RowHeight > 0 _
       And Not IsEmpty(xCell) _
       And IsNumeric(xCell.Value) _
    Then
      xTtl = xTtl + xCell.Value
      xCount = xCount + 1
    End If
  Next
  If xCount > 0 Then
    SUMVisible = xTtl
  Else
    SUMVisible = 0
  End If
End Function
```

I'd like to add an if statement (or something like it) that only sums the values if they're purchases ("V") but I can't seem to make it work. It either throws a value error or a spill error. I can't seem to find a thread that has a solution that might apply in this case. I know it's something simple but I'm somewhat new to VBA.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you re-inventing the `SUBTOTAL` function?

Comment: Yes,  pleas consider making this a formula instead using sumifs and subtotal

Comment: I'm trying to create a custom SUBTOTAL function so that in each column the function "hides" certain rows (the ones with "C" in this specific one). Since in every column there is a different criteria I'm trying to create my own SUBTOTAL function to just automate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sub Total with Criteria (UDF)

- If you have the values in `A1:A10` and the criteria in the `B` column, then in `Excel` for the criteria `"V"` you would use:

  ```
   =SumVisible(A1:A10,1,"V")
  ```

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Function SUMVisible(SumRange As Range, _
                    Optional ColumnOffset As Long, _
                    Optional Criteria As Variant) _
         As Double
    
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xTtl As Double
    
    Application.Volatile
    
    If ColumnOffset = 0 Or IsMissing(Criteria) Then
        For Each xCell In SumRange
            If xCell.ColumnWidth > 0 And _
              xCell.RowHeight > 0 And _
              Not IsEmpty(xCell) And _
              IsNumeric(xCell.Value) Then
                xTtl = xTtl + xCell.Value
            End If
        Next
    Else
        For Each xCell In SumRange
            If xCell.ColumnWidth > 0 And _
              xCell.RowHeight > 0 And _
              Not IsEmpty(xCell) And _
              IsNumeric(xCell.Value) And _
              xCell.Offset(, ColumnOffset).Value = Criteria Then
                xTtl = xTtl + xCell.Value
            End If
        Next
    End If
    
    SUMVisible = xTtl

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! In my case its in the the E column so the formula goes =SUMVisible(Vendas2020[Quantidade];5;"V") but unfortunately it throws a blank calculation when it shouldn't. I think its just a step away from working! Additional question: if in the FUNCTION I had more "optionals" does it create a SUMIFS?

Comment: You have to use `4` for column `E` as the example uses `1` for column `B`. I do not understand the `SUMIFS` question. In this version of the function you can only have one criteria.

Comment: Sorry I misstyped, i meant to put 4. Nevertheless it returns zero when it should not be zero. Regarding my question I meant if I can add more criteria to the FUNCTION code with another version of the code. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Criteria in this case is case-sensitive, i.e. `V<>v`. You could create a paramarray in the function, but then columnoffset cannot be optional. In Excel you would then use it like `=SUMVisible(A1:A10,4,"V","X","Y")`. But of course you have to add this functionality in the function i.e. modify part of the code.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because no matter how I change the formula is always throws a zero. I kept your original code and used column 4 and "V" criteria. I really can't understand why it doesn't work. As for adding criteria I get what you are saying. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where is `Vendas2020[Quantidade]` located? `ColumnOffset` means column position  according to the range. So if your range is in column `A` and criteria in `E`, then it is `4`, but if your range is in e.g. column `J` then for criteria in column `E` the offset is `-5`.

Comment: After seeing your last comment I think I know where my error is: 'Vendas2020[Quantidade]' is located in a sheet called "2020" but the 'SUMVisible' Function is being used in a different sheet called "Relatório" so it does not recognize a valid range for the calculation since the supposed column for thee calculation is in a different sheet.